# Extract div with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying extract all news headlines from [this link](https://www.cnn.com/search?q=new&from=0&size=10&page=1&sort=newest&types=all&section=politics) with Beautiful Soup. The headlines are located in a div that looks like this..

```
<div class="container__headline __headline" data-editable="headline">
      2022 midterm election results
  </div>
```

So far I have this..

```
headlines = soup.find('body').find_all('div',{"class": "container__headline __headline"})
for x in headlines:
    print(x.text.strip())
```

My code runs but nothing will print out. I have not seen this format to store a headline yet. Usually they are in an h4 tag or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Searched url is populated dynamically by JavaScript.So you can apply an automation tool something like selenium with bs4

**Example:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s=Service('./chromedriver')
driver= webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

for page in range(0,2):
    driver.get(f'https://edition.cnn.com/search?q=News&from=10&size=10&page={page}&sort=newest&types=all&section=travel')
    time.sleep(3)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    for h in soup.select('div[class="search__results-list"] > div'):
        title = h.select_one('div[class="container__headline __headline"]').get_text(strip=True)
        print(title)
```

**Output:**

```
Japan's long-awaited Ghibli Park is now open
4 airport workers fall ill at LAX from apparent gas leak
Spooky spots to explore from the US to Asia
The robotic falcon designed to help prevent bird strikes
How to survive a bear attack -- or better yet, avoid one altogether
Italy's weight loss secrets, the man who built a plane and more
Tourist strips naked on the steps of Italian cathedral
Some recent Disney price hikes outpace inflation. But the crowds keep coming for now
The spookiest cities in the US -- and why they still scare us
Travel news: Asia is reopening, and so are its coolest neighborhoods
Japan's long-awaited Ghibli Park is now open
4 airport workers fall ill at LAX from apparent gas leak
Spooky spots to explore from the US to Asia
The robotic falcon designed to help prevent bird strikes
How to survive a bear attack -- or better yet, avoid one altogether
Italy's weight loss secrets, the man who built a plane and more
Tourist strips naked on the steps of Italian cathedral
Some recent Disney price hikes outpace inflation. But the crowds keep coming for now
The spookiest cities in the US -- and why they still scare us
Travel news: Asia is reopening, and so are its coolest neighborhoods
```

**Solution using API URL:**

```
import requests
for page in range(0,2):
    res= requests.get(f'https://search.api.cnn.com/content?q=news&size=10&from={page}&page=1&sort=newest&sections=politics')
    #print(res)

    for item in res.json()['result']:
        headline=item['headline']
        print(headline)
```

**Output:**

```
Tiffany Trump's wedding assembles a family divided over its patriarch's political future
The latest on the 2022 midterm elections
US strike in Somalia kills 17 al-Shabaab fighters, US Africa Command says
How Brian Kemp took on Trump and created a blueprint for the GOP
2022 midterm election results
Biden aims to assert American leadership abroad at UN climate summit and G20
Neguse announces candidacy for Democratic caucus chair
'That certainly didn't help': GOP blame game spreads after midterm shortfalls
Why it takes so long to count West Coast votes
In pictures: The 2022 midterm elections
The latest on the 2022 midterm elections
US strike in Somalia kills 17 al-Shabaab fighters, US Africa Command says
How Brian Kemp took on Trump and created a blueprint for the GOP
2022 midterm election results
Biden aims to assert American leadership abroad at UN climate summit and G20
Neguse announces candidacy for Democratic caucus chair
'That certainly didn't help': GOP blame game spreads after midterm shortfalls
Why it takes so long to count West Coast votes
In pictures: The 2022 midterm elections
US observed Russian navy preparing for possible test of nuclear-powered torpedo
```